# Ansible Different hosts, different action

Tags: variables, ansible, hosts

with Ansible I need to copy a script in different clients/hosts, then I need to modify a line in the script. The line depends of the client and is not the same each times. 
Each hosts have the same name. Each clients name is different.

Something like that:

```
    lineinfile: >
      state=present
      dest=/path/to/myscript
      line="/personal line
    when: {{ clients/hosts }} is {{ client/host }}
```

As you can see, I have no idea about the way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Of course, I've read the documentation first, and still reading it at this moment. I've just didn't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there are some clients that have some specific hosts associated to them, and the line in this script will vary based on the client.

In that case, you should use group vars. I've included a simplified example below.

Set up your hosts file like this:

```
[client1]
host1
host2

[client2]
host3
host4
```

Use group variables like this:

File group_vars/client1:

```
variable_script_line: echo "this is client 1"
```

File group_vars/client2:

```
variable_script_line: echo "this is client 2"
```

Create a template file named yourscript.sh.j2:

```
#!/bin/bash
# {{ ansible_managed }}

script line 1
script line 2
# below is the line that should be dynamic
{{ variable_script_line }}
```

And then use the template module like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Deploy script to remote hosts
      template:
        src: /path/to/yourscript.sh.j2
        dest: /path/to/location/yourscript.sh
        mode: 0755
```

Note that the path to your source template will be different if you're using a [role][1].

Ultimately, when the play is run on `client1` vs `client2`, the content of the template will be written differently based on the variable (see more about [variable scopes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html)).

Comment: A really big thanks for your anwser. I've spent an afternoon  yesterday, and finally I gave up the way to compares a variable to a string.

Comment: Damn, I missed my edit: A really big thanks for your anwser to a newbie. I've spent an afternoon  yesterday, and finally I gave up the way to compares a variable to a string. As I only need to change one string in the script, I put the path in a variable and I've used "regexp" and "replace" functions. It's easier. But your solution with templates is better if I have more than one variable to change. I learnt a lot, thanks you for it. A little help is greater and more productive than a RT*M. I ever read the manual first !!!